# Writing a source code in Python

Tags: python

I have a Source code in C, I want to write it in Python. I have `.so` library files for my C code, is it possible to change `.so` files to `.py` lib files for execution?

If so, how can I execute my python files? 
I mean in order to run C in python, we use something like below:

```
gcc -shared -I/usr/include/python2.3/ -lpython2.3 -o myModule.so myModule.c
```

So is there is something like this to execute my python files or can I just use import command to execute?

Comment: It isn't clear to me whether you're asking to access dynamically linked libraries from python, or whether you're porting C code to python and are just wondering how python's module system works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html) module to load `so` files and use their functions.
Take a look at the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I'm newbie to programming, Started off with learning Python. Apologies if my question wasn't clear. I will re-write the source code (viz in C) to Python. But, I later realized that just writing the code in python will not be enough as the lib files for my C code are in C. My question is How should i execute my python code when the libraries are written in C? I do have .so and .a files in the lib.

Comment: @AARon, you are still very unclear. If you have an `so` file that you want to excute via Python, it's quite easy using `ctypes`. Other methods of translating C code to python are definitely less productive.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.. Yes, I have an so file and I want to execute it via Python, so i'll take a look at Python's types.